# Math puzzles suitable for printing on a mug

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education, puzzle

I need to design a cup for a reception for first-year college students and i'm searching for some challenging and entertaining math puzzle or game to use.
Previous years it has been used the "Three Utilities Problem", but i'm looking for something different or (at least) less known.

So far I have thought about:

- *Nine Dot puzzle*
- *Some Tessellation puzzle*

Do you know another Puzzle or game of this style ? (that can be printed on a cup)

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about the [Missing Square Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_square_puzzle)

Comment: *"that can be printed on a cup"* ... Please be more explicit about this constraint. Were you able to print the "Three Utilities" design in a way that exploited the handle to solve the puzzle?

Comment: With *"that can be printed on a cup"* i mean that can be played/solved only using the design printed on the cup, and maybe a marker

Comment: Is there a way you could reference the Monty Hall problem?

Comment: @RaúlAstete: Yes, but what flexibility does the printing process give you? Are you limited to an image that wraps-around the mug, avoiding the handle? Can you print on the bottom? On the *inside* bottom (perhaps for a message like "Now we await the theorems", a reference to the Erdos quote "A mathematician is a machine for turning coffee into theorems")?

Comment: It will be really cool, but i can print only on the outside of the cup (not including the handle)

Comment: Is the cup cylindrical? What are its proportions?

Comment: Yes, it's cylindrical, but i can use a 12cm x 8,5cm rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i've used a Hex gameboard for the mugs

This is the final result:

[image]

Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 7):

Challenge: divide the surface of the mug into seven connected regions such that each one is adjacent to the other six. In other words, embed $K_7$ on a torus.

Comment: This is a brilliant mug challenge - or could be embedded in the design - great answer!

Answer (score 0):

A "How many squares" puzzle can easily be printed on a cup.

[image: Determine the number of squares.]